# Sum of powers in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

I'm trying to implement a method to work as follows `foo(5) = 5^4 + 4^3 + 3^2 + 2^1 + 1^0 = 701` using recursion. I've been trying to follow the logic but I keep getting errors. can someone guide me?

```
(define (foo  n) ; size-n problem
( cond ( (= (- n 1) 0 ) ; stopping condition
   0 ); return value
(else (+ ( expt  n  (- n 1) ) ( foo (- n 1) ) ) ))) ; size-m problems
```

Comment: As far as I know this doesn't look Prolog at all. This looks like `lisp`

Comment: This is a very unclear question. Your title is *Prolog* recursive logic". You're showing what looks like Lisp code and saying *I keep getting errors*. Then *can someone guide me?*. What are you doing that's creating errors? What errors are you seeing exactly? Are you trying to create a working Lisp program or a working Prolog program? To get your Lisp code to work, replace `define` with `defun` and `else` with `t`.

Comment: Can someone guide me to fix the errors. what is not understandable about that.

Comment: @lurker Also I know the difference between prolog and lisp but I made a mistake in the title because I'm currently working on both. This website's mission statement is to help programmers find answers so you could've simply indicated my mistake without being rude.

Comment: @Shahad: You originally formulated this as a Prolog question. So please do not change it to mean something else. If you change your mind, please ask a new question.

Comment: *Can someone guide me to fix the errors. what is not understandable about that.* What is not understandable about it is that you haven't said exactly what the errors are, or what action you performed that resulted in those errors. All we can see is a question that's titled and tagged with prolog, but shows some Scheme code.

Answer (score 2):

If you tagged the question correctly, you want to answer this in Prolog, but your code fragment suggests you use `lisp` (or a language that I don't know).

In Prolog you write predictes. For your problem, there are two cases:

1. The case where `N` is less than or equal to zero, which is zero:

   ```
   foo(N,0) :-
       N =< 0,
       !.
   ```
2. The inductive case when `N` is greater than `0`. In that case we calculate `foo` for `N-1` and add up `N^(N-1)`:

   ```
   foo(N,S) :-
       N1 is N-1,
       foo(N1,T),
       S is T+N^N1.
   ```

You can simply write  program containing the two cases:

```
foo(N,0) :-
   N =< 0,
   !.
foo(N,S) :-
   N1 is N-1,
   foo(N1,T),
   S is T+N^N1.
```

And test it as follows:

```
?- foo(-1,S).
S = 0.

?- foo(0,S).
S = 0.

?- foo(1,S).
S = 1.

?- foo(2,S).
S = 3.

?- foo(3,S).
S = 12.

?- foo(5,S).
S = 701.
```

You can akso make th is predicate more safer from looping by adding a check for the inductive case:

```
foo(N,0) :-
    N =< 0,
    !.
foo(N,S) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N-1,
    foo(N1,T),
    S is T+N^N1.
```

Or you can further boost the predicate's performance using an accumulator:

```
foo(N,S) :-
    foo(N,0,S).

foo(N,S,T) :-
    N > 0,
    !,
    N1 is N-1,
    Q is S+N^N1,
    foo(N1,Q,T).
foo(N,S,S) :-
    N =< 0.
```

This version also checks first whether `N > 0` before `N =< 0` because it is a much more likely scenario: after one `N =< 0` we stop recursion whereas the `N > 0` will be called *N-1* times. Using an accumulator enables a optimization technique called *tail recursion*.

Comment: Mnmn: This is now just slow.

Comment: @false: just slow? I agree one better uses an accumulator for this.

Comment: ... and not very idiomatic. That is: next time, you will make this error again.

Comment: @false: of course: once passed 20, the brain no longer is that flexible. Although a befriended physician says this is to protect one against psychosis ;)